# Numer of (distinct?) $d$ dimensional irreducible representations

Tags: group-theory

I found a footnote on page 140 of [this book](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/0391) that reads:

> For a general $d$-dimensional quasicrystal, there is more than one $d$-dimensional irreducible representation. For the case of two-dimensional pentagonal symmetry, which describes the original Penrose tilings, there are two distinct two-dimensional representations of the pentagonal group.

From which my take-home message is: for *regular* crystals in $d$ dimensions, there is only one $d$ dimensional irreducible representation.

But then why does the dihedral group of order $n$ (even, for instance) have $(n-2)/2$ two-dimensional irreducible representations, as listed [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups)?